# Laravel on Ubuntu 14.10 with Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to start working on a Laravel project on my Ubuntu system. All my projects are in the `~/Documents/Projects/` folder as usual. I always use Vagrant individually for these projects, so each of them has a virtual environment.

I tried to do the same with Laravel. I installed the Laravel installer via Composer, and made a new project with the command `laravel new myproject`. Then I went inside the folder and initialized a new Vagrant environment with `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32 | vagrant up`. The virtual machine started up as usual, but when I tried to check if the installation is ok at `localhost:2222` I got the following error:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
Protocol mismatch.
```

I tried to init vagrant in the `myproject/public` folder too, but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What SSH-related output do you receive during `vagrant up`?

Comment: That's all SSH-related: http://pastebin.com/gnQ3xn06

Comment: Are you using the `vagrant ssh` command to connect to the virtual machine?

Comment: I just noticed that vagrant forwarded all my ports to :2222 for some reason, including ssh. Is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: It is normal for port 22 on the virtual machine to be forwarded to port 2222 on the host. The protocol mismatch error indicates that there is another problem, perhaps in the way that you are attempting to connect to the box. What command or process are you using when you receive the protocol mismatch error?

Comment: I can SSH into the box with no problem. I get this error when I type in my browser localhost:2222 or 127.0.0.1:2222

Comment: Yes, that is expected; Trying to connect to an SSH server with a web browser will lead to a protocol-mismatch error because the browser cannot communicate via the SSH protocol. 

Instead, connect to the port that is forwarded to your VM's port 80.

Answer (score 2):

In a default Vagrant configuration, port 2222 forwards SSH, and port 8080 forwards HTTP. To access your Web site through a Web browser on your host machine, visit http://localhost:8080/.

If you try to visit port 2222 using a Web browser, SSH doesn't know how to respond to an HTTP request, which is why you're seeing the error you are.

---

If this doesn't work, check your `Vagrantfile` for a line like this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

Your looking for the line with `guest: 80`. The integer following `host:` is the port you use on your host machine to access HTTP on your guest machine.

Comment: it doesn't work with `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8888` either, I just get a `server not found` error. :( Here's my vagrantfile: http://pastebin.com/VhVq6NK1 and here's my terminal output: http://pastebin.com/u1ECcyqx

Comment: @TrisztánThar You need to set up an HTTP server (like Apache or nginx) and an application server (usually PHP-FPM). Vagrant is just an interface between you, your host machine, and a base OS that doesn't know how to serve Web pages. If you're not familiar with Linux system administration, I'd recommend using [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead), which uses Vagrant.

Comment: I'm constantly using Vagrant on other projects. I just tried with a previous one, and `localhost:8080` works as intended, I only have this problem with Laravel.

Comment: @TrisztánThar Did you set up those projects? Do they also use `hashicorp/precise32` as the base box?

Comment: Yes. one of them uses another box, which also works. All the others are with the precise32.

Comment: @TrisztánThar You must be using some form of [provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html).

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you said:

> I just noticed that vagrant forwarded all my ports to :2222 for some reason, including ssh.

Each port to be served on the virtual machine should be mapped to a unique port on the host. For example, the following mapping is common

```
VM Port    Host Port
--------------------
20     ->      2222
80     ->      8080
3306   ->      3306
```

If you see something like:

```
VM Port    Host Port
--------------------
20     ->      2222
80     ->      2222
3306   ->      2222
```

there is a problem with the configuration in your Vagrantfile. Check the mappings there to ensure that each VM port is mapped to a unique host port. Run `vagrant reload` to restart the VM and remap the ports.

Next, log into the virtual machine via SSH and verify that a web server is running. Do

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

or

```
sudo service nginx status
```

or attempt to connect directly to port 80 to see if anything responds:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

If nothing responds, your web server is not running. Update your base image or provisioning script to start your web server when the virtual machine is launched.

If a service is responding on port 80, go back to the host and try again to access the website via the correctly-mapped port. For example, if port 80 on the VM is now mapped to port 8080 on the host, open your browser and browse to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

You should now see the Laravel default home page.

Comment: Also, consider using Homestead. It prepares your entire Laravel VM out of the box.